# Remove hyphen between numbers only if hyphen follows more than 2 digits

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Remove hyphen only if hyphen followed more than 2 digits?

Input:

```
101|9881|Customer contact on 12-01-2015|AXD

102|9882|Declined sales. 122-333-1234 contact|XYZ
```

Output:

```
101|9881|Customer contact on 12-01-2015|AXD

102|9882|Declined sales. 1223331234 contact|XYZ
```

I have used this...

```
sed 's/([0-9])-([0-9])/\1\2/g' inputfile
```

but it replaces hyphens for all hyphenated numbers.

Any help please?

Comment: Why shouldn't `12-01-2015` be converted to `12-012015`? The 2nd hyphen IS followed by more than 2 digits. Hang on - your subject says `hyphen follows more than 2 digits` but your text says `hyphen is followed by more than 2 digits`. Which do you want? or is it either or both?

Comment: Basically the idea behind it is to maintain date as it is and to combine the other numbers other than date.

Comment: Then the approach should simply be to remove hyphens from any string of numbers and hyphens that don't match a date regexp, e.g. in awk it'd be `/[0-9-]+/ && !/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/`. Anyway, looks like you have an answer you're happy with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify "more than two":

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{3,\}\)-/\1/g' <<< '101|9881|Customer contact on 12-01-2015|AXD
> 102|9882|Declined sales. 122-333-1234 contact|XYZ'
101|9881|Customer contact on 12-01-2015|AXD
102|9882|Declined sales. 1223331234 contact|XYZ
```

In basic regular expressions (what GNU sed without options does), `()` match literal parentheses, you have to escape them for a capture group. Same for braces around quantifiers: `\{3,\}` is "three or more".

If your sed supports it (for GNU sed: `-r` option), you can use extended regular expressions, which simplifies the command to

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{3,})-/\1/g'
```